# Best option for sortable/draggable layout selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, layout, jquery-ui-sortable, draggable

For my current project, I need to make a layout selector where certain elements can be dragged and repositioned by the user, similar to this mockup:

[image]

So far, I have been able to replicate something similar using JQuery UI and Sortable, however I am currently stuck only on the first level of control, where vertical elements can be repositioned.  I am having difficulty figuring out what the best approach is to handle the nested horizontal elements (like the content/sidebar sections).

Ideally, I need this to not only position the order of each section (header, body, footer, etc.) but also the alignment of sections (content to left, sidebar to right and vice versa).

Comment: Do you still have that problem? If you do, are you able to provide a jsfiddle demo?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't come across this until just now.  I ended up not using this solution in my final implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe have a look at [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/), a powerful layout editor.